# Subscribijng multiple evewnt handlers to single event not working c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a series of `validation events` ,which I want all be grouped to minimize code.

say I have this `event` which is exactly the same for about 4 more text fields.

**Event Handlers**

```
  private void txt_SurName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {   // Convert User input to TitleCase
                if (useUnkownEntity(txt_SurName.Text))
                {
                    return; 


                }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_SurName.Text))
                {
                    epSurname.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
                }

                else if (util.IsAllLetters(txt_SurName.Text))
                {
                    epSurname.Clear(); txt_SurName.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_SurName.Text); _IsValid = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    epSurname.SetError(txt_SurName, "InValid Surname"); _IsValid = false;
                }

            }

I have tried this however to no luck

     this.txt_ForeName.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_SurName_Validating);






private void txt_ForeName_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_ForeName.Text))
            {
                epForeName.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }
            else if (util.IsAllLetters(txt_ForeName.Text))
            {
                epForeName.Clear(); txt_ForeName.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_ForeName.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epForeName.SetError(txt_ForeName, "InValid Forename, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Country Validating event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void txt_Country_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Country.Text))
            {
                epCountry.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.IsAllLetters(txt_Country.Text))
            {
                epCountry.Clear(); txt_Country.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_Country.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epCountry.SetError(txt_Country, "InValid Country, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Alternative Vlaiditn event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void txt_Alt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Alt.Text))
            {
                epAlternative.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.numValidation(txt_Alt.Text))
            {
                epAlternative.Clear(); txt_Alt.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_Alt.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epAlternative.SetError(txt_Alt, "InValid Alternative entry!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Landline Validating event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void txt_LndLine_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_LndLine.Text))
            {
                epLandline.Clear();
                _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.numValidation(txt_LndLine.Text))
            {
                epLandline.Clear(); txt_LndLine.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_LndLine.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epLandline.SetError(txt_LndLine, "InValid LandLine Number, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// PostCode Validating event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void txt_Postcode_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Postcode.Text))
            {
                epPostcode.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.IsAllLettersOrDigits(txt_Postcode.Text))
            {
                epPostcode.Clear(); txt_Postcode.Text = txt_Postcode.Text.ToUpper(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epPostcode.SetError(txt_Postcode, "InValid Postcode, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Mobile Number Validating event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void txt_Mobile_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Mobile.Text))
            {
                epMobile.Clear(); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else if (util.numValidation(txt_Mobile.Text))
            {
                epMobile.Clear(); txt_Mobile.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_Mobile.Text); _IsValid = true;
            }

            else
            {
                epMobile.SetError(txt_Mobile, "InValid Mobile, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
            }
    }
```

**Events**

```
// 
            // DOB
            // 
            this.DOB.AutoSize = true;
            this.DOB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 88);
            this.DOB.Name = "DOB";
            this.DOB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
            this.DOB.TabIndex = 88;
            this.DOB.Text = "DOB";
            // 
            // txt_County
            // 
            this.txt_County.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 226);
            this.txt_County.Name = "txt_County";
            this.txt_County.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 23);
            this.txt_County.TabIndex = 7;
            this.txt_County.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_County_Validating);
            this.txt_County.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_Locality
            // 
            this.txt_Locality.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 312);
            this.txt_Locality.Name = "txt_Locality";
            this.txt_Locality.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 23);
            this.txt_Locality.TabIndex = 9;
            this.txt_Locality.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_Locality_Validating);
            this.txt_Locality.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_Country
            // 
            this.txt_Country.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 268);
            this.txt_Country.Name = "txt_Country";
            this.txt_Country.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 21);
            this.txt_Country.TabIndex = 8;
            this.txt_Country.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_Country_Validating);
            this.txt_Country.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_HouseName
            // 
            this.txt_HouseName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 352);
            this.txt_HouseName.Name = "txt_HouseName";
            this.txt_HouseName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 21);
            this.txt_HouseName.TabIndex = 10;
            this.txt_HouseName.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_HouseName_Validating);
            this.txt_HouseName.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_StreetName
            // 
            this.txt_StreetName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 393);
            this.txt_StreetName.Name = "txt_StreetName";
            this.txt_StreetName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 23);
            this.txt_StreetName.TabIndex = 11;
            this.txt_StreetName.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_StreetName_Validating);
            this.txt_StreetName.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_Town
            // 
            this.txt_Town.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
            this.txt_Town.BackColorTransparent = true;
            this.txt_Town.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
            this.txt_Town.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.txt_Town.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 186);
            this.txt_Town.Name = "txt_Town";
            this.txt_Town.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 20);
            this.txt_Town.TabIndex = 6;
            this.txt_Town.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_Town_Validating);
            this.txt_Town.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_ForeName
            // 
            this.txt_ForeName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Honeydew;
            this.txt_ForeName.BackColorTransparent = true;
            this.txt_ForeName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.txt_ForeName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
            this.txt_ForeName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 23);
            this.txt_ForeName.Name = "txt_ForeName";
            this.txt_ForeName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 21);
            this.txt_ForeName.TabIndex = 0;
            this.txt_ForeName.Validated += new System.EventHandler(this.txt_ForeName_Validated);
            this.txt_ForeName.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            // 
            // txt_SurName
            // 
            this.txt_SurName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 64);
            this.txt_SurName.Name = "txt_SurName";
            this.txt_SurName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 21);
            this.txt_SurName.TabIndex = 1;
            this.txt_SurName.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_SurName_Validating);
            this.txt_SurName.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            //
```

any ideas would be very gratefull

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What error are you getting? What unexpected behavior you are seeing? Share the code which attached multiple handlers to the single event.

Comment: You could use the `sender` argument instead of a specific textfield

Comment: I'm not getting any error I was expecting my txt_ForeName.Validating        handler to subscribe to my txt_Surname Event and so on with all of my common events

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have added the rest of the Event handlers to the above code

Comment: I want to be able to only have say thre event handlers subscribing to the events with th winform project

Comment: What happens when you try to attach multiple handlers to the same event? `this.txt_ForeName.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_SurName_Validating);` where did you write this code?

Comment: That's how I attached them but seems to n ot work at all and no validation is completed I wrote inside the designer class

Comment: Any ideas lads ?

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed but if you attached multiple handlers to event of one textbox they all will fire only when that particular textbox gets validated. Not when other textboxes get validated...

Comment: ah ok ,s o what would be thye best approach to to achieve my result ? will I have to include the evnt on evry textbox?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya any ideas around this mate ?

Comment: The best approach is to have separate event handler for validating each textbox.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have already approached this way nut its rely cluttered could you me an example if I'm just been unsure, just need to optimize the    existing evenest an example would  appreciated

Comment: say all of my events need to be group regarding the functionality on the event ForeName, SurName StreetName County. These for events follow the same rulls of validation so do the need to have their on Handler

Comment: Not near the computer right now. Will post some example tomorrow.